# How to link winsock.lib?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp, winsock

In my C++ class, I use sockets.

I have some errors when linking because, in my opinion, the library winsock.lib is missing.

I included these:

```
#ifdef WIN32
  #include <winsock.h>         
  typedef int socklen_t;
  typedef char raw_type;       
#endif
```

How can I link the library `winsock.lib`?
I use Windows XP and Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The lib file of winsock is "ws_32.lib" (or "ws2_32.lib"), please make sure you've added it.

Comment: OK, a question.. Is there a library called winsock.lib?

Comment: You'd need a time machine to go back to the 16-bit version of the SDK.

Comment: I think the correct name of the library is ws2_32.lib

Comment: Yes, there is. In the [Windows Mobile SDK 5.0 for PocketPC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42) for example.

Comment: Cannot find ws_32.lib.

Answer (score 11):

I am unable to find direct link shows what lib to use, but if you study [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will find out, that *windows sockets 1.1* is supported through `WSOCK32.DLL`, that mean, possible, that you want `WSock32.Lib`, instead of `Ws2_32.lib` for *windows socket version 2*.

`WSock32.Lib` is a part of `Windows SDK` (I have v6.0A, v7.0A installed, both has this library)

Answer (score 0):

One way is you may add a pragma directive to cpp file:

`#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`

Another way is that you may to provide it to project settings, using project that builds your binary (dont do it from library project, if you have many under your solution)

Third variant is to provide it as a command line flags if you invoke linker from command line