# Can't open socket. c++

Tags: c++, sockets, lnk2019

I'm trying to open socket. But it gives a link Error (LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function') at WSASTartup, WSAGetLastError, socket, htons. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is a source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
string server; int port;
void login_info()
{
    cout << "Enter IP Address: ";
    cin >> server;
    cout << "\nEnter Port: ";
    cin >> port;
    cout << endl;
}

int main () 
{
    char buffer[1024];
    login_info();
    cout << "Trying to connect...\n";
    if (WSAStartup(0x202, (WSADATA *) &buffer[0])) //Оно что-то запускает. Знать бы что..
    {
        cout << "WSAStart error #" << WSAGetLastError(); //Но если оно пизданётся, то появится ошибка :3
        return -1;
    }
    //Тут предположительно поднимается сам сокет.
    SOCKET connection;
    connection=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //Проверка на то, что он есть?
    if (socket<0) 
    {
        cout << "Socket error #" << WSAGetLastError(); //Но если оно пизданётся, то появится ошибка :3
        return -1;
    }
    sockaddr_in dest_addr; //Тут опять происходит, что-то мне непонятное..
    dest_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;      
    dest_addr.sin_port= htons (port);
    HOSTENT *hst;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like you're missing a lib in the link....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to link in the winsock ws_32.lib library. I'm not sure what tool/ide you are using but [how to link winsock.lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249886/how-to-link-winsock-lib) has some details.

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit - Might need to look for Ws2_32.lib now.

Comment: Thank u. But it seems that there is no ws_32.lib (either ws32.lib too) for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2012