# socket errors gcc can't get functions in WinSock2.h

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I literally read every post on stackoverflow that is somewhat similar to my case and none worked. this is a snippet of IRC.cc after my modifications : 
(I am using library cpIRC if you want to see IRC.h its on google)

```
#include "IRC.h"

#ifdef __WIN32__
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
//#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")


#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define closesocket(s) close(s)
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#endif

... code ... ERROR IS ON THIS LINE:
    irc_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (irc_socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return 1;
    }

...code ...
```

ERRORS are as such :

```
||=== Build: Debug in botv (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\IRC.o||In function `ZN3IRC5startEPciS0_S0_S0_S0_':|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|107|undefined reference to `socket@12'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|112|undefined reference to `gethostbyname@4'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|115|undefined reference to `closesocket@4'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|120|undefined reference to `htons@4'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|122|undefined reference to `connect@12'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|125|undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|127|undefined reference to `closesocket@4'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|137|undefined reference to `closesocket@4'|
obj\Debug\IRC.o||In function `ZN3IRC10disconnectEv':|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|163|undefined reference to `shutdown@8'|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|165|undefined reference to `closesocket@4'|
obj\Debug\IRC.o||In function `ZN3IRC12message_loopEv':|
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\CPP\botv\IRC.cc|196|undefined reference to `recv@16'|
||=== Build failed: 11 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have read tons of answers about winsock2.h that is how I ended up with the includes you see and their order. it is still showing the same error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm confused, how is that a duplicate? The guy is obviously trying to compile VC++ code (in particular using the Win32 socket library) with gcc (which uses the Posix model) -- that will never work.

Comment: hey Blindy I am using the windows version gcc found with codeblock when you download the binary version one has a compiler with it.

Comment: @Blindy _" that will never work"_ Good point!

Comment: Is name mangling is going on?  The winsock are all C functions I believe and these errors look like function name mangling is being done?

Comment: @Blindy getting the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: Many people seem to be linking with  -lws2_32

Comment: I triedthat didnt work. I read about 20 web pages for solutions this is hour 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to link winsock.lib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249886/how-to-link-winsock-lib)

Comment: @EJP - nope. That's a VS-centric question. This question pertains to GCC.

Answer (score 2):

The errors are caused by a missing library. The missing library is ws2_32 and is found in the library file libws2_32.a (on Windows).

You actually attempt to link to this library with the line:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")
```

However, this is only recognized by the MSVC++ compiler while you are using the GCC compiler.

To solve the problem, remove the pragma-line (or leave it there, it probably doesn't matter), and add the library to the project. I think you add libraries in Code::Blocks by:

1. Right click on project and choose 'Build options'
2. Under the 'Linker settings' tab there is a field called 'Link libraries'
3. Click 'Add', type 'ws2_32' and click ok
4. Save settings

If the library is in the usual folder, this will eliminate your linker errors.

Comment: adding 'ws2_32' worked, while adding path to 'libws2_32.a' didn't

Answer (score 0):

These are *linker* errors. You need to link to the appropriate Winsock .lib library.

Comment: which would be ? I am running windows 8.1

Comment: Actually, he's using gcc (or at least, MinGW) - therefore, the actual filename does _not_ have a `.lib` extension. Instead, he will need to link against `libws2_32.a`