# How to programmatically obtain adapter's IPv4/6 interface metric on Windows using C/C++ APIs?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-programming

On Win10 I can run **get-netinterface** in powershell to display InterfaceMetric for each interface.
Is there a C/C++ Win API that would let me retrieve it programmatically?

The metric can be set in adapter's TCP/IP settings:

[image]

Comment: _"Is there a C/C++ Win API"_ There's the C Winsock API, yes. Any particular question about that? Here's one question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249886/how-to-link-winsock-lib

Comment: Which specific function in Winsock API will give me interface metric?

Comment: There is no WinSock function to get this information. There is, however, an [IP Helper function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) that can.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the question was so quickly downgraded. Should I have listed all the [useless] APIs/functions that I looked at to 'show research effort'? And what is not clear in the question? Could you please help me understand the reason for the downgrade so I could be better next time I post a question?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The helper function might be exactly what I was looking for. It returns Ipv4Metric and IpV6Metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a C/C++ Win API that would let me retrieve [InterfaceMetric] programmatically?

Use [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses). See the `Ipv4Metric` and `Ipv6Metric` members of the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` struct.

Comment: how to change the metric with c++？

Comment: @dragonfly I don't know, sorry.  That would be a good question to post separately

Answer (score 2):

Win32 has provided these APIs for you.

Please refer to these APIs, eg: GetIpForwardTable

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getipforwardtable2

These APIs can get and modify router info, it is just designed for your requirements.

Codes for modify metrics like this:

```
    MIB_IPINTERFACE_ROW entry_row;
    InitializeIpInterfaceEntry(&entry_row);
    entry_row.InterfaceIndex = index1_;
    entry_row.Family = AF_INET;
    int ret = GetIpInterfaceEntry(&entry_row);
    if (ret != NO_ERROR) {
        log_info("GetIpInterfaceEntry ret:%d:", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    entry_row.Metric = m1;
    entry_row.UseAutomaticMetric = false;
    entry_row.SitePrefixLength = 0;
    int api_ret = SetIpInterfaceEntry(&entry_row);
```